# How to convert and optimize this SQL query in SqlKata

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlkata

I have this SQL query and I need to convert it SqlKata

```
SELECT VVIAGGIO AS VIAGGIO, ISNULL(AEAN,'') AS EAN
FROM 
SALDI V INNER JOIN ARTICOLI A ON VARTI=AARTI
INNER JOIN ORDI OT ON VSTAB=OTSTAB AND VMAGA=OTMAGA AND VAGG=OTRAGG
  WHERE VORDI ='21'
  AND VHOST ='68'
ORDER BY VPROG, AARTI
```

I don't know how to structure it because here is  `ISNULL()`, `INNER JOIN`..
I already checked [SqlKata](https://sqlkata.com/docs/select) select instruction.

Any suggestions on how to optimize and convert this query in SqlKata?

Comment: Must admit, it seems an odd decision to alias your objects, and then never use said aliases.

Comment: Joins are straight forward https://sqlkata.com/docs/join . For ISNULL(), see if there's a COALESCE() option instead, as coalesce() is ansi standard but isnull() is specific to sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you need:

```sql
var query = new Query("SALDI as V")
    .Join("ARTICOLI as A","A.ARTI","V.ARTI")
    .Join("ORDI as OT",j => j.On("OT.STAB","V.STAB")
          .On("V.MAGA","OT.MAGA")
          .On("V.AGG","OT.RAGG")
    )
    .Where("V.ORDI","21")
    .Where("V.HOST","68")
    .Select("V.VIAGGIO")
    .SelectRaw("ISNULL(V.AEAN,'') as EAN")
    .OrderBy("V.PROG", "A.ARTI")
```

Comment: Try it in the Playground: https://sqlkata.com/playground?code=var%20query%20%3D%20new%20Query(%22SALDI%20as%20V%22)%0A%20%20%20%20.Join(%22ARTICOLI%20as%20A%22%2C%22A.ARTI%22%2C%20%22V.ARTI%22)%0A%20%20%20%20.Join(%22ORDI%20as%20OT%22%2Cj%20%3D%3E%20j.On(%22OT.STAB%22%2C%22V.STAB%22).On(%22V.MAGA%22%2C%22OT.MAGA%22))%0A%20%20%20%20.Where(%22V.ORDI%22%2C%2221%22).Where(%22V.HOST%22%2C%2268%22)%0A%20%20%20%20.Select(%22V.VIAGGIO%22).SelectRaw(%22ISNULL(V.AEAN%2C'')%20as%20EAN%22)%0A%20%20%20%20.OrderBy(%22V.PROG%22%2C%20%22A.ARTI%22)